# Having to refresh after putting data into google datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to create a user registration form for my project but every time I try to put the data into the google datastore, it doesn't immediately reflect in the database.

I redirect to a welcome page after the registration is complete. But i have to refresh the page after redirection to get the corresponding information for the user. To fix this, i am using the put statement twice. can someone please tell me a better method to solve this?

```py
a=User(username=uname, pass_hash=make_secure(str(pswrd)),parent=users_key())
a.put()
a.put()
```

Comment: Yes. This is because of eventual consistency. Putting twice won't help; what you need to do is to get the item by key.

Comment: Like @DanielRoseman said, Datastore’s consistency tends to be eventual, but there are ways to [structure data for strong consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency). Could you please update your question to provide us more information about how you were originally retrieving the user data, after registration?

Comment: I am retrieving the user data by doing a simple GQL query on the datastore. Also @DanielRoseman can you please tell me how to get the item by key.

Comment: Please read the doc pessolato linked.

Comment: If you confirm to me which Client Library you are using, I will gladly provide an example on how to do a strongly consistent Ancestor Query or a "Key Lookup".

Comment: Currently i am using the Google Datastore NDB client library (for python2).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve strongly consistent reads with the Datastore NDB Client Library, you can either do a “Key Lookup” or an Ancestor query (in case you need to fetch multiple recently stored entities).

The example below stores a new Guest in **/sign** and redirects the request to the root with the Event (parent) ID and a url_safe ID for the recently created entity:

```
    # When accessed /sign we check if an Event with ID 1111 exists
    event_key = ndb.Key('Event', 1111)
    event = event_key.get()
    # If it does not exist we create one
    if event is None:
        event = Event(key=event_key, title=’Party’)
        event.put()

    # We store a new Guest
    name = '<SOME_RANDOM_STRING>'
    guest = Guest(name=name, parent=event_key)
    guest.put()
    print(guest)

    # And redirect the request to the main route with the information we need to fetch these entities
    # You could use the urlsafe() method for both, I chose to use separate methods just as an example
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(
        {
            'event_id': event_key.id(),
            'guest_id': guest.key.urlsafe()
            }))
```

Once the user is redirected to the main route:

```
    event_id = self.request.get('event_id')
    # If the url comes with an event ID, then we proceed with querying for Guests
    if event_id:
        # We generate a key with the ID
        event_key = ndb.Key('Event', int(event_id))

        # And we execute an Ancestor query to fetch all guests of that event
        guests = Guest.query(ancestor=event_key).fetch()
        print(guests)

        # Here we do a basic “Key Lookup” just to fetch the newly created guest
        guest_id = self.request.get('guest_id')
        if guest_id:
            guest_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=guest_id)
            guest = guest_key.get()
            print(guest)

    self.response.out.write('Check your Logs!')
```